# How to order dispatch executions in Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Recently I am trying to learn Redux and trying to use it in my simple app, but I have just faced a problem.

I've got two dispatch in my use effect and I need them to work one after another beacuse in other case my app won't work.

Right now it's

```
dispatch(dataAction({name: doc.data().name, surname: doc.data().surname, uid: doc.data().uid, profilePic: doc.data().url}));
dispatch(loginAction())
```

and i need loginAction to work after dataAction, but beacuse dataAction owns payload, it executes after loginAction. Is there good way to order them?

Comment: is dataAction asynchronous? And thus need await or .then?

Comment: do you have possibility to use dispatch(loginAction()) inside dataAction in the end?